# How should I initialise the paths for SKMapInitSettings?

Tags: android, skmaps

I'm trying to setup the Skobbler Maps SDK for android and I'm have trouble initialising it. I can't find on the documentation what path values should I set on 'SKMapInitSettings'. I get the following exception:

```
05-29 16:09:29.713: E/AndroidRuntime(18545):
com.skobbler.ngx.SKMapsPathsNotInitializedException: SKMaps paths were not
initialized. Set the following in SKMapInitSettings : mapResourcesPath,
currentMapViewStyle, mapsPath.
```

What are the appropriate values for these paths? Why aren't they set by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [Android demo project](http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download) there is an example on how the paths are set:

```
    SKMapsInitSettings initMapSettings = new SKMapsInitSettings();
    // set path to map resources and initial map style
    initMapSettings.setMapResourcesPaths(app.getMapResourcesDirPath(),
            new SKMapViewStyle(app.getMapResourcesDirPath() + "daystyle/", "daystyle.json"));
```

Where `app.getMapResourcesDirPath` points to:

```
    File externalDir = getExternalFilesDir(null);

    // determine path where map resources should be copied on the device
    if (externalDir != null) {
        mapResourcesDirPath = externalDir + "/" + "SKMaps/";
    } else {
        mapResourcesDirPath = getFilesDir() + "/" + "SKMaps/";
    }
    ((DemoApplication) getApplication()).setMapResourcesDirPath(mapResourcesDirPath);
```

Comment: It would be advisable to add this information in the documentation: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec003